# Do loop SAS programming

Tags: loops, sas

I have table as below:

```
id comp1 comp2 comp3    comp4 comp5 

1  12     14    45       78   74
2  25     45    36       88   45
```

I want to create a table if any comp1-comp10 has 36?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WHICHN()

```
data want;
set have;
array comp(5) comp1-comp5;
if whichn(36, of comp(*))>0;
run;
```